# IOS Getter Setter cannot apply to Google Map

Tags: ios, pointers, getter-setter

I am tryin to use the getter setter class for Objective C using strings, int, and floats. But when it comes to the execution, it shows that there has bad access of the variables pass by reference tarting from this line:

```
[self setState:valueState];
```

Applpication Part:

```
  CheckPoints *myCar=[[CheckPoints alloc] init];
    [myCar setState:1];
    [myCar setLatitude:12.12312313];
    [myCar setLongitude:123.12312312313];
     NSString *theTextValue = @"Destination";
    [myCar setDesp:theTextValue];
```

The below is my code:

Checkpoints.m

```
#import "CheckPoints.h"

@implementation CheckPoints

@synthesize desp = _desp;
@synthesize latitude = _latitude;
@synthesize longitude = _longitude;
@synthesize state = _state;


- (NSString *) getDesp
{
    return desp;
}

- (float *) getLatitude
{
    return latitude;
}

- (float *) getLongitude
{
    return longitude;
}

- (int *) getState
{
    return state;
}

- (void)setDesp:(NSString *)valueDesp {
    [self setDesp:valueDesp];
}

- (void)setLatitude:(float )valueLatitude {
  //  self.latitude = valueLatitude;
    [self setLatitude:valueLatitude];
}

- (void)setLongitude:(float )valueLongitude {
    [self setLongitude:valueLongitude];
}

- (void)setState:(int )valueState {
    [self setState:valueState];  <---this segment
}

@end
```

Checkpoints.h

```
#import <GoogleMaps/GoogleMaps.h>
#import <Foundation/Foundation.h>

@interface CheckPoints : NSObject<CLLocationManagerDelegate> {

    NSString *desp;
    float* latitude;
    float* longitude;
    int* state;
}


@property (nonatomic, strong) NSString* desp;
@property  (nonatomic, assign) float* latitude;
@property  (nonatomic, assign) float* longitude;
@property  (nonatomic, assign) int* state;

- (NSString *)getDesp;
- (float *)getLatitude;
- (float *)getLongitude;
- (int *)getState;

- (void)setDesp:(NSString *)valueDesp;
- (void)setLatitude:(float )valueLatitude;
- (void)setLongitude:(float )valueLongitude;
- (void)setState:(int )valueState;

@end
```

Answer (score -1, accepted):

You are making an infinite loop over here. Inside the setter, you should set the value in instance variable. You are calling setter method again from the body of setter method. So, it will create an infinite loop. This will overrun your stack and your application will crash. See below code to make your setter method proper.

```
- (void)setState:(int )valueState {
    _state = valueState;
}
```

Modify other setter methods in the same way.

Comment: After chaining this.. it gets 


2014-06-09 16:30:36.966 marker[2426:60b] 0
2014-06-09 16:30:36.968 marker[2426:60b] 0.000000
2014-06-09 16:30:36.970 marker[2426:60b] 0.000000
2014-06-09 16:30:36.971 marker[2426:60b] (null)

Comment: Did you modify all setter in the same way?

Comment: I have to change the setter of other variables as state = $valueState

Comment: I don't know how to se getter setter if String is involved !

Comment: If you are not doing anything special, you need not to write getter and setter methods. Compiler will write it instead of you.